# Need help centering a table in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a python web app checkers right now so I'm building my templates for it. However, I'm unable to center the main checkerboard onto screen without breaking the aspect ratio of it.

Here's what it looks like right now:

[image: Result]

Here's what I want it to look like:

[image: What it "should" look like]

Can you suggest some changes I should make to my code?

```css
ol {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
    }
    
    table td,
    table th {
      padding: 0
    }
    
    .c0 {
      border-right-style: solid;
      border-bottom-color: #000000;
      border-top-width: 1pt;
      border-right-width: 1pt;
      border-left-color: #000000;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-right-color: #000000;
      border-left-width: 1pt;
      border-top-style: solid;
      background-color: #000000;
      border-left-style: solid;
      border-bottom-width: 1pt;
      width: 56.7pt;
      border-top-color: #000000;
      border-bottom-style: solid
    }
    
    .c2 {
      border-right-style: solid;
      border-bottom-color: #000000;
      border-top-width: 1pt;
      border-right-width: 1pt;
      border-left-color: #000000;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-right-color: #000000;
      border-left-width: 1pt;
      border-top-style: solid;
      border-left-style: solid;
      border-bottom-width: 1pt;
      width: 56.7pt;
      border-top-color: #000000;
      border-bottom-style: solid
    }
    
    .c7 {
      color: #000000;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-decoration: none;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      font-size: 11pt;
      font-family: "Arial";
      font-style: normal
    }
    
    .c6 {
      padding-top: 0pt;
      padding-bottom: 0pt;
      line-height: 1.15;
      orphans: 2;
      widows: 2;
      text-align: left;
      height: 11pt
    }
    
    .c1 {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-decoration: none;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      font-size: 50pt;
      font-family: "Arial";
      font-style: normal
    }
    
    .c12 {
      padding-top: 0pt;
      padding-bottom: 0pt;
      line-height: 1.15;
      text-align: center;
      height: 11pt
    }
    
    .c3 {
      padding-top: 0pt;
      padding-bottom: 0pt;
      line-height: 1.0;
      text-align: center;
      height: 11pt
    }
    
    .c4 {
      padding-top: 0pt;
      padding-bottom: 0pt;
      line-height: 1.0;
      text-align: center
    }
    
    .c10 {
      margin-left: auto;
      border-spacing: 0;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin-right: auto
    }
    
    .c8 {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      max-width: 451.4pt;
      padding: 72pt 72pt 72pt 72pt
    }
    
    .c11 {
      orphans: 2;
      widows: 2
    }
    
    .c9 {
      margin-right: 5.1pt
    }
    
    .c5 {
      height: 56.7pt
    }
    
    .title {
      padding-top: 0pt;
      color: #000000;
      font-size: 26pt;
      padding-bottom: 3pt;
      font-family: "Arial";
      line-height: 1.15;
      page-break-after: avoid;
      orphans: 2;
      widows: 2;
      text-align: left
    }
    
    .subtitle {
      padding-top: 0pt;
      color: #666666;
      font-size: 15pt;
      padding-bottom: 16pt;
      font-family: "Arial";
      line-height: 1.15;
      page-break-after: avoid;
      orphans: 2;
      widows: 2;
      text-align: left
    }
    
    li {
      color: #000000;
      font-size: 11pt;
      font-family: "Arial"
    }
    
    p {
      margin: 0;
      color: #000000;
      font-size: 11pt;
      font-family: "Arial"
    }
    
    h1 {
      padding-top: 20pt;
      color: #000000;
      font-size: 20pt;
      padding-bottom: 6pt;
      font-family: "Arial";
      line-height: 1.15;
      page-break-after: avoid;
      orphans: 2;
      widows: 2;
      text-align: left
    }
    
    h2 {
      padding-top: 18pt;
      color: #000000;
      font-size: 16pt;
      padding-bottom: 6pt;
      font-family: "Arial";
      line-height: 1.15;
      page-break-after: avoid;
      orphans: 2;
      widows: 2;
      text-align: left
    }
    
    h3 {
      padding-top: 16pt;
      color: #434343;
      font-size: 14pt;
      padding-bottom: 4pt;
      font-family: "Arial";
      line-height: 1.15;
      page-break-after: avoid;
      orphans: 2;
      widows: 2;
      text-align: left
    }
    
    h4 {
      padding-top: 14pt;
      color: #666666;
      font-size: 12pt;
      padding-bottom: 4pt;
      font-family: "Arial";
      line-height: 1.15;
      page-break-after: avoid;
      orphans: 2;
      widows: 2;
      text-align: left
    }
    
    h5 {
      padding-top: 12pt;
      color: #666666;
      font-size: 11pt;
      padding-bottom: 4pt;
      font-family: "Arial";
      line-height: 1.15;
      page-break-after: avoid;
      orphans: 2;
      widows: 2;
      text-align: left
    }
    
    h6 {
      padding-top: 12pt;
      color: #666666;
      font-size: 11pt;
      padding-bottom: 4pt;
      font-family: "Arial";
      line-height: 1.15;
      page-break-after: avoid;
      font-style: italic;
      orphans: 2;
      widows: 2;
      text-align: left
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
</head>

<body class="c8">
  <p class="c6"><span class="c7"></span></p>
  <a id="t.e9fce3736f9827f2937bda8f2c218a755be7fe1b"></a>
  <a id="t.0"></a>
  <table class="c10">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="c5">
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">a</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">b</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">c</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">d</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3 c9"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c5">
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">e</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">f</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4 c11"><span class="c1">g</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">h</span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c5">
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">i</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">j</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">k</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">l</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c5">
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c5">
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c5">
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">a</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">b</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">c</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">d</span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c5">
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">e</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">f</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">g</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">h</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c5">
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">i</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">j</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">k</span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c3"><span class="c1"></span></p>
        </td>
        <td class="c0" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <p class="c4"><span class="c1">l</span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p class="c11 c12"><span class="c7"></span></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Put everything required to show the problem *in the question*, without links. Please format your html. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Its not tabular data. As such you shouldnt use a table in the first place. The right tool would be CSS-Grid.

Comment: simply remove the c8 class yo are adding to your body

Answer (score 2):

First, you shouldnt use a table for this as this is not tabular data. You want to use a CSS-Grid as it creates a table like layout with far less hard-coding HTML-wise then a table.

Wrap the table inside a `flexbox` and use `justify-content: center` to align it in the horizontal center. Then use `align-items: center;` to align the board in the vertical center.

The `grid` itself should have a `column width` equal the `row height`. That way they maintain to be squares and not depend on the line height.

```css
/* centers the board horizontally and vertically in the screen */

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* creates a grid (table like layout) */
  
.board {
  display: grid;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: min-content;
}


/* sets the height and width in landscape mode to fit the screen responsivly */

@media only screen
  and (orientation: landscape) {
    .board {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 10vh);
      grid-auto-rows: 10vh;
    }
}


/* sets the height and width in portrait mode to fit the screen responsivly */

@media only screen
  and (orientation: portrait) {
    .board {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 10vw);
      grid-auto-rows: 10vw;
    }
}


/* centers the element within a grid-card (cell) */

.board > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* coloring the cells to look like a chessboard */

.board :nth-child(-n+8):nth-child(odd),
.board :nth-child(n+9):nth-child(-n+16):nth-child(even),
.board :nth-child(n+17):nth-child(-n+24):nth-child(odd),
.board :nth-child(n+25):nth-child(-n+32):nth-child(even),
.board :nth-child(n+33):nth-child(-n+40):nth-child(odd),
.board :nth-child(n+41):nth-child(-n+48):nth-child(even),
.board :nth-child(n+49):nth-child(-n+56):nth-child(odd),
.board :nth-child(n+57):nth-child(-n+64):nth-child(even){
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <!-- 1st row -->
  <div class="A1">a</div>
  <div class="B1"></div>
  <div class="C1">b</div>
  <div class="D1"></div>
  <div class="E1">c</div>
  <div class="F1"></div>
  <div class="G1">d</div>
  <div class="H1"></div>
  
  <!-- 2nd row -->
  <div class="A2"></div>
  <div class="B2">e</div>
  <div class="C2"></div>
  <div class="D2">f</div>
  <div class="E2"></div>
  <div class="F2">g</div>
  <div class="G2"></div>
  <div class="H2">h</div>
  
  <!-- 3rd row -->
  <div class="A3">i</div>
  <div class="B3"></div>
  <div class="C3">j</div>
  <div class="D3"></div>
  <div class="E3">k</div>
  <div class="F3"></div>
  <div class="G3">l</div>
  <div class="H3"></div>
  
  <!-- 4th row -->
  <div class="A4"></div>
  <div class="B4"></div>
  <div class="C4"></div>
  <div class="D4"></div>
  <div class="E4"></div>
  <div class="F4"></div>
  <div class="G4"></div>
  <div class="H4"></div>
  
  <!-- 5th row -->
  <div class="A5"></div>
  <div class="B5"></div>
  <div class="C5"></div>
  <div class="D5"></div>
  <div class="E5"></div>
  <div class="F5"></div>
  <div class="G5"></div>
  <div class="H5"></div>
  
  <!-- 6th row -->
  <div class="A6"></div>
  <div class="B6">a</div>
  <div class="C6"></div>
  <div class="D6">b</div>
  <div class="E6"></div>
  <div class="F6">c</div>
  <div class="G6"></div>
  <div class="H6">d</div>
  
  <!-- 7th row -->
  <div class="A7">e</div>
  <div class="B7"></div>
  <div class="C7">f</div>
  <div class="D7"></div>
  <div class="E7">g</div>
  <div class="F7"></div>
  <div class="G7">h</div>
  <div class="H7"></div>
  
  <!-- 8th row -->
  <div class="A8"></div>
  <div class="B8">i</div>
  <div class="C8"></div>
  <div class="D8">j</div>
  <div class="E8"></div>
  <div class="F8">k</div>
  <div class="G8"></div>
  <div class="H8">l</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternative `margin: 0 auto` is a much simpler solution if applied to `.board`. flexbox is entirely unnecessary and overly complicated for something so simple.

Comment: it only centers horizontally not vertically. for a vertical center you need flexbox. Full responsivness is the key for games. Nobody want to scroll in a board game.

Comment: Nowhere in the question does it mention centering vertically.